# PHP echo in JS innerHTML

Tags: php, javascript

I am working with an external JS file, which is being called in my PHP file.  In my JS file, I have some of the following:

```
var label = document.createElement("Label");
label.innerHTML = "<?php echo $string; ?>";
f.appendChild(label);
```

How else can I append the PHP variable to the textbox, because this does not seem to be working?

Comment: What textbox are you talking about?

Comment: You should really be using `json_encode()` around any arbitrary data being echoed into JavaScript.

Comment: @Brad why that? What's wrong with echoing a string like that?

Comment: @Zim84, If you just echo blindly, you need to do all of the escaping yourself or you create invalid JavaScript and break everything.  Worse yet, if you are using data that comes from the user, you potentially open yourself up to some nasty XSS attacks.  Using `json_encode()` guarantees that the data is just inserted into the script, and also takes care of type problems for you as well.

Comment: @Brad, Thank you. So the correct code for that line would be `label.innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($string); ?>;`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Zim84, Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score -1):

You need to treat .js files as PHP if you want to do that. Otherwise, in your PHP script, you can do the following...

```
<script>var __GLOBAL_VAR = "<?php echo $string; ?>";</script>
... output of stuff ...
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Then in your scripts.js, you can reference `__GLOBAL_VAR` - or whatever you want to name it.

Comment: what he's trying to say is that your webserver must also look inside .js files for php-tags. But I assume most servers are already configured like that.

Comment: Servers are not configured to parse PHP in JS files without explicit AddType rules in .htaccess or in the apache config files...

Comment: @RobW, Same with `.php` files.  And really, a better solution here is probably to just use `<script src="yourJSGeneratingPHPScript.php">` instead.  Then, you don't have to mess with it (such as on some shared hosting, where it isn't configurable).

Comment: ^ I like this approach as well. Good one!